# How do I emit a method with a pre-loaded MethodInfo local variable?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I would like to emit a method that has a variable, which I can do. But, I would like to store in that variable a MethodInfo object, which is a reference to a different (non emitted) method.

I could emit the opcodes to call typeof(someClass).GetMethod(...), but it would be more efficient if I could simply load a token for this MethodInfo and bake it directly into the variable.

So, to rephrase, I'm trying to find out of its possible to emit , let's say a "load object" opcode and pass it an object at emit-time that will be loaded onto the stack at runtime. (OpCodes.Ldobj gave some kind of error when I tried this).  Or, am I forced to emit opcodes that will do this at runtime?

Comment: I think this is possible. Eric Lippert once blogged about a possible infoof C# operator that would use this.

Comment: Could you give a little context on the reason behind, to make the problem a little clearer for me/us?

Comment: @usr [The article you're talking about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx) is about the syntactical problems of `infoof`, not how it could be implemented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't just load any general object in IL, because there is no way to store it in IL (with the exception of some special types like `string`). You could work around that using serialization (for types that support it), but I don't think that's what you want. Also, [`ldobj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldobj.aspx) serves quite a different purpose.

But you can do this for `MethodInfo` in a way that's very similar to what C# does for the `typeof` operator. That means:

1. using the [`ldtoken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldtoken.aspx) instruction to get a [`RuntimeMethodHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtimemethodhandle.aspx)
2. calling [`MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wk6z0dh.aspx) to get a `MethodBase`
3. cast it to `MethodInfo`

The whole code to generate a method that returns the `MethodInfo` could look like this:

```
MethodInfo loadedMethod = …;
var getMethodMethod = typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod(
    "GetMethodFromHandle", new[] { typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle) });

var createdMethod = new DynamicMethod(
    "GetMethodInfo", typeof(MethodInfo), Type.EmptyTypes);

var il = createdMethod.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, loadedMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getMethodMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(MethodInfo));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var func = (Func<MethodInfo>)createdMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<MethodInfo>));
Console.WriteLine(func());
```